# How can I make snapping and select face 3D

Tags: snapping

My snapping isn't 3D. When select for eg. *Face* the square (in the photo) isn't 3D, and that makes snapping so hard, because my icing passes through the donut.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Consider that we know nothing about the situation you are currently in. Please help us and add more detail to your post in the first place to give an answer, eg. add a drawing of what *exactly* you do want to snap.

Comment: Hi! Your *edit* does not really help. Please take your time and read my comment again. -> Add at least a screenshot of your scene describing your issue in detail and consider to share your blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Also please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi! Now I put some photos.

Comment: Blender has a built-in screenshot function. *Main Menu > Window > Save Screenshot*

Comment: Thanks. Did you understand my question?

Comment: Way better now, voted to re-open it. I suggest add a link to the tutorial at that current time like https://youtu.be/jmSgsaNSQ6s?t=313 (Youtube > Right Click > Copy Video URL at current time)

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Thank you very much!